# AWS Cognito Email Verification and Sign in

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Aws Cognito for Email verification. After I sign up, i will be receiving an email for verification purpose. Once i click on the button to verify my account, is it possible to directly log me into the application without having to enter the email and password details again?

Comment: Yes you could store the token you're getting from the backend in local storage. Then you should check the local storage value before app initialization at app component.

Comment: @MirentafazAli How to view the token from the backend in cognito? Also, how to store it in the localstorage?